# angular tree control complex items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, tree

I am using angular-tree-control to implement a tree.

In the html-template of each tree-item are a lot of ng-if for checking, if icons should be shown and stuff. Also each item contains a directive to create a context menu.

So if i have a lot of items(>1000), the tree slows down, so im wondering what would be a better way implementing it?

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. It's useful to post your code and explain with an example what the timing issues are, e.g. 100 items, 1000 items etc?

Answer (score 0):

As @Spangen sugests, your question needs more info...

If your trying to render more than 1000 nodes in one go, you will probably need to build a specialized solution (e.g. in a Angular directive)... I don't know of any generic AngularJS solutions that will keep up.

If you don't start out with that many nodes expanded, but the problem is instead occurring as you expand nodes and that brings you above the 1000 total nodes, then perhaps https://plnkr.co/edit/RxKuOD62Wy6PblmgzFIx could be of interest for you...

It stays fairly response even beyond 10000 nodes in my current machine, although it certainly does slow down as the memory footprint grows... Since we don't know the complexity of your nodes it just has 10 ng-if's which reacts to the current level of the tree...

The template:

```
  <ul dx-start-with="app.root" class="list-unstyled">
    <li ng-repeat="node in $dxPrior.nodes">
      <i class="glyphicon btn btn-primary" ng-class="node.expanded ? 'glyphicon-chevron-down':'glyphicon-chevron-right'" ng-click="app.toggle(node)"></i> {{ node.name }}

      > This is node <span ng-bind="$index"></span>
      at level <span ng-bind="$dxLevel"></span> 
      under <span ng-bind="$parent.$parent.$dxLevel"></span>

      <div ng-if="$dxLevel === 0" >ZERO</div>
      <div ng-if="$dxLevel === 1" >ONE</div>
      <div ng-if="$dxLevel === 2" >TWO</div>
      <div ng-if="$dxLevel === 3" >THREE</div>
      <div ng-if="$dxLevel === 4" >FOUR</div>
      <div ng-if="$dxLevel === 5" >FIVE</div>
      <div ng-if="$dxLevel === 6" >SIX</div>
      <div ng-if="$dxLevel === 7" >SEVEN</div>
      <div ng-if="$dxLevel === 8" >EIGHT</div>
      <div ng-if="$dxLevel === 9" >NINE</div>

      <ul ng-if="node.expanded" dx-connect="node" style="list-style-type: square"></ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

(Note, if your on a newer version of AngularJS, then recursive directives is also a contender, I would assume that they could offer a bit more performance, but I can't say how much, the above was something I could quickly do on a old sample I already had lying around)

---

But if you are trying to render more than 1000 nodes in one go that even stalls a little bit, but I would have to ask, why would you do that?... As a user, is that what I wan't to see?... it sounds like way to much information to provide the user with all at once in the form of a tree...

(Had it been dots on a Map or something else graphical, then I can see it makes sense to display that amount of information, but not in a tree)...